# All Tests fails with PHP Fatal error: cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, phpunit

I am getting a strange behavior with PHPUnit and I cannot figure if I'm doing something wrong or if it is a bug from the test framework. Here is my case:

My project has several classes: BsInput, BsEmail, BsHidden, BsNumber. BsEmail, BsHidden and BsNumber extend BsInput. All classes have unit test classes (BsInputTest for BsInput, BsEmailTest for BsEmail, etc.).

Each unit test executed individually goes fine.

Now if I try to run all tests in my project, i get an error and message "PHP Fatal error: cannot redeclare class B in /some/path/to/B.php on line 80".

Here is the content of each file:

BsInput.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/BsInputControl.php";

class BsInput extends BsInputControl {
    ...
}
```

BsEmail.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/BsInput.php";

class BsEmail extends BsInput {
    ...
}
```

BsHidden.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/BsInput.php";

class BsHidden extends BsInput {
    ...
}
```

BsNumber.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/BsInput.php";

class BsNumber extends BsInput {
    ...
}
```

BsInputTest.php

```
require_once "../colibri/bs/BsInput.php";

class BsInputTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    ...
}
```

BsEmailTest.php

```
require_once "../colibri/bs/BsEmail.php";

class BsEmailTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    ...
}
```

BsHiddenTest.php

```
require_once "../colibri/bs/BsHidden.php";

class BsHiddenTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    ...
}
```

BsNumberTest.php

```
require_once "../colibri/bs/BsNumber.php";

class BsNumberTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    ...
}
```

Now the last little thing that drives me insane: if I comment out all code in BsHidden.php and BsHiddenTest.php, PHPUnit All Tests execution goes smooth over BsNumber and following classes !

Has anyone already seen something similar ? Any clues what I should look at to get my problem solved ?

I have tried an ugly workaround: inserting the following code in BsInput.php

```
var_dump(class_exists('BsInput', FALSE));
if (class_exists('BsInput', FALSE)) { return; }
```

And I get this result:

```
bool(true)
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class BsInput in /.../BsInput.php on line 87
```

I have looked at many issues up to now including the ones above, but up to now I couldn't find any solution.

- [PHPUnit loads all classes at once. Causes PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668466/phpunit-loads-all-classes-at-once-causes-php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-clas)
- [PHPUnit Test Suite - Cannot redeclare class Mocking & Concrete classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742390/phpunit-test-suite-cannot-redeclare-class-mocking-concrete-classes)
- ["Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class" ... but the class was not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668630/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-but-the-class-was-not-declared)

I have also tried updating PHPUnit to the latest version (4.6), with no more success.

My platform is:
Mac OS X 10.10
PHP 5.5.20
PHPUnit 4.6.6
Netbeans 8.0.2 (if this has anything related)

Any clue anyone ?

After trying to solve this i finally deleted my `BsHidden.php` file, the attached test file and recreated them exactly (I mean with exact same content I copy/pasted)... And now it works ! This really makes me think of a bug somewhere between PHP and PHPUnit.

However a quick & dirty workaround seems to be:

1. copy-paste file and unit test file contents to another file
2. delete problematic file and unit test file if any)
3. re-create file and unit test file and paste contents

Comment: Kudos forrequire_once... Everyone use include () when they want require_once :o

Comment: In several places you have something like: `require_once __DIR__ . "/BsNumber.php";` and then `class BsNumber extends BsInput`. Am I missing something here, or class `BsNumber` is not defined in `__DIR__ . "/BsNumber.php"` but in different file?

Comment: No. I define one class per file, and each file is named after the class it defines.

Comment: Can you give us a brief explanation why are you requiring the same file your class is defined in? You have ` BsNumber` class and at the top `require_once "BsNumber.php"` which is the exact same file... And the reason is?

Comment: My apology. There were mistakes in the source code examples, now corrected. Files `BsEmail.php`, `BsHidden.php` and `BsNumber.php` all `require_once __DIR__ . "/BsInput.php";`.

Answer (score 3):

I have finally identified my issue. It seems that there is a PHP bug, at least on my platform.

PHP's manual says (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) that names resolution in PHP4 are case-insensitive on case-insensitive systems, while PHP5 handles such problems.

Here is the behavior I get on my platform (Mac OS X 10.10, PHP 5.5) :

Assuming I have a file `A.php` that defines a `A` class and the following code:

```
<?php
require_once 'A.php';
require_once 'a.php';
?>
```

Second `require_once` fires the `Can not redeclare class error`. So in PHP5.5 on Mac OS X at least names resolution is case insensitive, *but PHP still considers they are different files anyway*.

Answer (score 0):

Is you just use `class_exists`, use it like this:

```
if (!class_exists('BsInput', FALSE)) { 
    class BsInput extends BsInputControl {
        // ToDo
    }
}
```

I do not know why this error is otherwise generated - do you use *everywhere* require_*once* explicit?

Comment: Yes, my workaround wasn't so nice. I have checked my whole code for any `require` instead of `require_once`, but i have none.